# Let $f_1,f_2,...,f_k$ be pairwise orthogonal nonzero vectors of $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Let $f_1,f_2,...,f_k$ be pairwise orthogonal nonzero vectors of $R^n$. Show that $ P = \frac{f_1f_1^T}{f_1^Tf_1} + \frac{f_2f_2^T}{f_2^Tf_2} + ... + \frac{f_kf_k^T}{f_k^Tf_k}$ is a projection matrix.

So, my textbook shows me that the definition of a projection matrix is $ P = PP$ but how do I use that to complete this proof?

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{f_if_i}{f_if_i}f_i$?

Comment: @fuglede the denominator should be dotted together not multiplied

Comment: @mp12345 Even assuming the "dotted together" makes sense, then what happens with the numerator?? It looks like you meant to do dot product in both numerator and denominator, but that hardly makes sense either as then you are multiplying each vector by $\;1\;$ ...

Comment: And then you get a sum of vectors where the result should be a matrix. Do we want something like $f_if_i^T$ somewhere?

Comment: yes sorry I forgot the T I just made a edit

Comment: @DonAntonio I have made a edit and forgot the T

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. Do you have an $f_i$ too much at the end of each summand?

Comment: No it was not. Sorry everyone I have made a edit to fix my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to simplify notation a bit, let $g_i = f_i / \lVert f_i \rVert$, so that the expression becomes

$$P = \sum_i g_ig_i^T.$$

Now, choose an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R^n}$ of the form $(g_1 \dots, g_k, e_{k+1}, \dots, e_n)$ for some suitable $e_{k+1}, \dots, e_n$. We are done, if we can show that $Pv = PPv$ for each of these basis vectors. If $v = e_j$ for some $j$, then

$$Pv = Pe_j = \sum_i g_ig_i^Te_i = \sum_i g_i 0 = 0,$$

and therefore also $PPv = P0 = 0$. If on the other hand $v = g_j$ for some $j$, then

$$Pv = Pg_j = \sum_i g_ig_i^Tg_j = g_jg_j^Tg_j = g_j,$$

and $PPg_j = Pg_j$.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
P^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{f_if_i^T}{f_i^Tf_i} \right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{f_jf_j^T}{f_j^Tf_j} \right) = 
\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{(f_i^Tf_i)(f_j^Tf_j)} f_i(f_i^Tf_j)f_j^T
$$
Now, note that $f_i^Tf_j = 0$ whenever $i \neq j$, which means we can rewrite the above as
$$
P^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{(f_i^Tf_i)^2} f_i(f_i^Tf_i)f_j^T
$$
now, show that this is the same as $P$.

Answer (score 0):

You have the matrix

$$P:=\sum_{m=1}^k \frac1{\left\|f_m\right\|^2}f_mf_m^t\implies PP=\sum_{m,n}^k\frac1{\left\|f_m\right\|^2\left\|f_n\right\|^2}f_mf_m^tf_nf_n^t$$

But $\;f_m^tf_n=0\;$ for all $\;m\neq n\;$ , so you're left in the above doulble sum only with the summands where $\;m=n\;$ :

$$\sum_{n=1}^k\frac1{\left\|f_n\right\|^2\left\|f_n\right\|^2}f_nf_n^tf_nf_n^t=\require{cancel}\sum_{n=1}^k\frac1{\left\|f_n\right\|^2\cancel{\left\|f_n\right\|^2}}\cancel{\left\|f_n\right\|^2}f_nf_n^t=P$$

Comment: The norms should be squared.

Comment: @fuglede Good catch, thanks. Edited.